# Solving sum of one variable with real exponents

Tags: summation, exponentiation, real-numbers

I'm working with an annoying maximisation problem at the moment. I've spent a long time Googling, but I'm not having much success and I suspect it would be simple enough if I had the right tools. I have to solve for $x$ something that is analogous to this $$ \sum_{i= 1}^n y_i x^{\epsilon_i} = B $$ where everything is in the real numbers, $y$ and $\epsilon$ depend on $i$. Is there any way for me to get $x$ in terms of the parameters in that expression?

Comment: Numerical methods only for the general case. Put an example of your choice and I shall try to show you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm actually working with the general case. The only thing I know about the values $y$, $\epsilon$, $B$ and $x$ is that they lie on the real numbers. Is it not possible to isolate $x$ when it's in this form?

Comment: I am afraid that the solution is not unique in general.

Comment: There is almost absolutely no hope to get analytical solutions and, as   Alexander Vigodner commented, there are probably multiple solutions (except if a lot of restrictions).

Comment: I think I may have explained this poorly. $y_i$, $\epsilon_i$ and $B$ are fixed parameters on the (positive) real numbers, and would be known in a particular case. $x$ is variable and does not depend on $i$. Sorry for bungling up the explanation.

If there's still no hope, I'll just go back to the drawing board.